# diff function says files are different when they are copies

Tags: perl, diff

I have a perl script that counts doublets in a text file, and summarizes the results. This works fine on my mock set of data (a.txt). This file is a short list of letters. My real data (winningStreak.txt) is much longer and the perl script fails to read the file.

```
alexhuhn@Ubuntu-MacPro:~/Desktop/Analysis$ perl doublet.pl a.txt
Name a file to save the results in
b.txt
alexhuhn@Ubuntu-MacPro:~/Desktop/Analysis$ perl doublet.pl winningStreak.txt
Name a file to save the results in
b.txt
```

I thought there was something wrong with my script, so I copied and pasted a.txt into winningStreak.txt. My perl script again did not read the file information.

I ran

```
alexhuhn@Ubuntu-MacPro:~/Desktop/Analysis$ diff a.txt winningStreak.txt 
1,5c1,5
< w
< w
< l
< l
< 
---
> w
> w
> l
> l
>
```

and everything is considered different, even though it was just copied and pasted. Does anyone know how I can circumnavigate this issue, as my real data (streak.txt) is much longer than my mock set (a.txt).

```
alexhuhn@Ubuntu-MacPro:~/Desktop/Analysis$ hexdump -C a.txt winningStreak.txt 
00000000 77 0d 0a 77 0d 0a 6c 0d 0a 6c 0d 0a 0d 0a 77 0a |w..w..l..l....w.| 
00000010 77 0a 6c 0a 6c 0a 0a |w.l.l..| 
00000017
```

Comment: I am going to guess that when you say you "copied" the file, you didn't actually copy it, but you did something else. I am also going to guess that this is about line endings, and that either of the files is from Windows.

Comment: @TLP When I copied, I highlighted and pasted into the winningStreak.txt document. I do not know why carriage returns would alter anything

Comment: @Сухой27 alexhuhn@Ubuntu-MacPro:~/Desktop/Analysis$ hexdump -C a.txt winningStreak.txt
00000000  77 0d 0a 77 0d 0a 6c 0d  0a 6c 0d 0a 0d 0a 77 0a  |w..w..l..l....w.|
00000010  77 0a 6c 0a 6c 0a 0a                              |w.l.l..|
00000017

Comment: `perl -i -pe 'y|\r||d' a.txt winningStreak.txt` will remove CR from files.

Comment: @Сухой27 sorry, do not know how to format that better, but this also says something is different

Comment: @alex Note the character `0d` in your hexdump. This is `\r`, a non-printable whitespace character.

Comment: @alex also notice how for every `0a` in the dump of winningStreak.txt there is `0d 0a` in the dump of a.txt. This might be easier to see if you dump the files separately: `hexdump -C a.txt`, then `hexdump -C winningStreak.txt`. Now an interesting question is, why does your Perl script require the `0d` in order to work correctly?

Comment: Thank you for all comments. I ran     perl -i -pe 'y|\r||d' a.txt     and removed all the CR, now my perl script does not work at all. I will work with that and sort it out, but it appears it is the CR that are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, there must a difference in non-printable characters. One has Windows line endings (CRLF), and the other has unix line endings (LF).

Use `dos2unix` or some other tool to convert it, or use `s/\s+\z//` instead of `chomp` to remove the line endings.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was dos2unix, as @ikegami said. I used a modified perl script to alter the CRs, as @Сухой27 said.

I ran

```
alexhuhn@Ubuntu-MacPro:~/Desktop/Analysis$ perl -i -p -e 's/\n/\r\n/' winningStreak.txt
```

and it altered the endings so that my perl script worked.

Thanks for all the help!